# PHP function time() gives inaccrate time

Tags: php, time

The following code is supposed to give me the current time.

```
<?php
    echo '<p>time : ' .date("H:s", time());
?>
```

However, the hour:minute is inaccrate at all. For example, right now it's 19:23, and my browser may give me

```
time : 19:48
```

If I refresh, the minute will go up.

My PHP version is: `PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 (cli) (built: Nov  2 2022 13:35:25) (NTS)`.

Comment: date('s') means current time's seconds value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. It was my mistake. I should be using "H:i" instead of "H:s" for the format.